# How do I generate a TimedeltaIndex from a column of timestamps where the each TimeDelta is generated with reference to the previous timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of timestamps:

```
Timestamp

2015-10-01 00:00:08                                       
2015-10-01 00:00:18                                       
2015-10-01 00:00:28                                       
2015-10-01 00:00:38                                       
2015-10-01 00:00:48                                       
2015-10-01 00:00:58                                       
2015-10-01 00:01:08                                       
2015-10-01 00:01:17
```

and I want to generate TimeDeltas from the timestamp where each TimeDelta value takes reference from the previous timestamp like this:

```
Timestamp                TimeDelta

2015-10-01 00:00:08     00:00:00.000                         
2015-10-01 00:00:18     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:28     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:38     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:48     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:58     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:01:08     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:01:17     00:00:09.000
```

But instead i'm getting this:

```
Timestamp                TimeDelta

2015-10-01 00:00:08     00:00:00.000                         
2015-10-01 00:00:18     00:00:10.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:28     00:00:20.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:38     00:00:30.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:48     00:00:40.000                      
2015-10-01 00:00:58     00:00:50.000                      
2015-10-01 00:01:08     00:01:00.000                      
2015-10-01 00:01:17     00:01:09.000
```

I'm using the following code:

```
df['TimeDelta'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Timestamp'])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `diff` method to compute the difference of adjacent rows:

```
df['TimeDelta'] = df['Timestamp'].diff().fillna(0)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['2015-10-01 00:00:08', '2015-10-01 00:00:18',
   '2015-10-01 00:00:28', '2015-10-01 00:00:38', '2015-10-01 00:00:48',
   '2015-10-01 00:00:58', '2015-10-01 00:01:08', '2015-10-01 00:01:17']})
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['TimeDelta'] = df['Timestamp'].diff().fillna(0)
print(df)
```

yields

```
            Timestamp  TimeDelta
0 2015-10-01 00:00:08   00:00:00
1 2015-10-01 00:00:18   00:00:10
2 2015-10-01 00:00:28   00:00:10
3 2015-10-01 00:00:38   00:00:10
4 2015-10-01 00:00:48   00:00:10
5 2015-10-01 00:00:58   00:00:10
6 2015-10-01 00:01:08   00:00:10
7 2015-10-01 00:01:17   00:00:09
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I've tried it but unfortunately it told me that `.diff()` was deprecated and told me to use [.difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.difference.html?highlight=difference) instead. I tried `df['TimeDelta'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['date']-df['date'].shift(1))` and its working!

Comment: The `DatetimeIndex.diff` method is deprecated. But the `Series.diff` method is not. Since `df['Timestamp']` is a Series (of dtype `datetime64[ns]`), there should be no problem using `df['Timestamp'].diff()`.

Comment: You're right! It does work! I made a mistake, I was using the following earlier: `df['TimeDelta'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Timestamp']).difference().fillna(0)` Thanks for your help!